# API4 GroupContact does not update Subscription History?

Tags: groups, apiv4

When I use the API4 GroupContact update I do not have the option to change the date of the change (which is kept in civicrm_subscription_history). Also, when I use the update to set the status to Removed, the status in the group contact is changed indeed but nothing is added to the civicrm_subscription_history.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?
(CiviCRM version 5.41.2)

Answer (score 1):

APIv4's `GroupContact` was updated circa 5.49 to auto-update the `SubscriptionHistory` (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/22419 - contemporaneously with the question here).